# Wrong values when squaring two RGB pixel values (OpenCV + Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to calculate the ssd between two rgb images and I found that the values returned contained negative values which is weird because ssd squares the differences before summing them. So, I dissected the problem and it turns out that the problem is with the squaring.

This is my ssd function:

```
def ssd(kernel_left, kernel_right):
    return np.sum((kernel_left- kernel_right)**2)
```

Here is how I dissected the problem:

```
print(kernel_left[1,1]) # = [61 57 56]
print(kernel_right[1,1]) # = [87 59 29]
print(kernel_left[1,1] - kernel_right[1,1])  # = [-26  -2  27]
print((kernel_left[1,1] - kernel_right[1,1])**2) # = [-92   4 -39]
```

which does not make any sense to me how the squaring yields wrong and negative values.

Comment: I bet you're working on int8

Comment: cast your values to double before doing the operations

Comment: Okay, no problem. Also, has something changed or do you need to supply an axis to np.sum if you want it to return a vector? I think it returns a single number (total sum) without a second argument?

Comment: @Miki I'm working on it. And thank you, it worked perfectly.